# Test page_caching with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Does anyone know how to test page_caching in Rails using RSpec without having to check to see if the cache file has been created for each request? Something more like Controller.performs_page_caching(:action).should be_true?

I've tried looking over the net, but I haven't found anything that works.

Comment: You should put your solution as a separate answer... it helps to see what people vote on as a good answer and what you've checked off as your own answer to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a solution. You override the caches_page class method for the ApplicationController class and setup an after filter which sets a header 'x-page-cached' to true. Then in your test scripts include a macro for page_cached? which will check to see if response.headers['x-page-cached'] is true or not. Only do this for the test and development environments.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like integration test. For example you could try write request spec and count somehow number of db queries.